# Inserting/Retrieving a file from Sybase

Tags: java, sap-ase

I am trying to insert a file containing into a Sybase database. I am using JConnect-7.0.7

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE blob_test (  
blobVar IMAGE  
)
```

I am inserting the image using:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO blob_test VALUES (convert(binary,?))";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
File image = new File(filePath);
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
int ilen=(int) image.length();
stmt.setBinaryStream(1, fis, ilen);
stmt.execute();
```

And trying to retrieve the image using:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate= new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
List<Blob> result = jdbcTemplate.query(
         "SELECT blobVar FROM blob_test", new Object[] {}, new RowMapper() {  
                @Override
                public Blob mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    return rs.getBlob(1);
                }
            });

for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
    Blob b = result.get(i);
    BufferedOutputStream os;

    os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("output"+i+".zip")));
    os.write(b.getBytes(1, (int) b.length()));
    os.flush();
    os.close();
 }
```

However, when I execute my code it outputs 1kb zip files that are corrupted. My code works exactly as it should for an oracle database.

Alternatively, I have also tried this code to retrieve the file:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate= new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
List<InputStream> result = jdbcTemplate.query(
         "SELECT * FROM blob_test", new Object[] {}, new RowMapper() {
                @Override
                public InputStream mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    return lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, 1);
                }
            });

for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
   InputStream in = result.get(i);
   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("outputTest"+i+".zip"));
   byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
   int len = 0;

   while ((len = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
       out.write(buff, 0, len);
   }

   out.flush();
   out.close();
}
```

However, when I run this code I get an exception:

```
java.io.IOException: JZ0I9: This InputStream was closed.
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseIOException(Unknown Source)  at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseIOException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.RawInputStream.checkMe(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.RawInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.RawInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at blobtester.BlobTester.getOracleBlob(BlobTester.java:86)
    at blobtester.BlobTester.main(BlobTester.java:34)
```

Again, this works for oracle. Is there anything I'm missing that is different about Sybase? Is the file being saved/retrieved correctly?

**edit:
It turns out the problem was inserting the file into Sybase. I changed the code to:**

```
File image = new File(filePath); 
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource); 
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO blob_test VALUES (?)", new Object[] {new SqlLobValue(fis, (int)image.length(), lobHandler)}, new int[] {Types.BLOB});
```

**And it worked for both Sybase and oracle. Thanks.**

Comment: are the stored blobs in the sybase and oracle dbs the same?

Comment: both have 1 column: blobVar. The type in sybase is IMAGE and the type in oracle is BLOB

Comment: i'm asking whether the values stored in the table are the same.  can you check with a gui?  that way you can tell if the problem is with the insert or the select.

Comment: I dont have access to a GUI to check that. Iv managed to insert and retrieve using oracle and checked the CRC of the original and retrieved file. I dont have a way of doing this with Sybase.

Comment: compare to this guy's code? http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/9931-sybase-and-blob-storing

Comment: i would maybe download a GUI:  squirrel sql (http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)  and try get it working.  I've used it with Sybase before.  Then you can see if it's your code or not.

Comment: Thanks. I tried some of the code from the link and it worked. Edited question with solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code from this link worked:  http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/9931-sybase-and-blob-storing

[Just adding an answer, to close the question.]